# How to count the output of a conditional statement in python?

Tags: python

i made this code and i want it to tell me how many times it used to find the number i put in, and i want to tell how many times it should repite the action of finding the "stop_at"

```
print 'first write the random int (lowest number first)'

imp1 = float(raw_input())
imp2 = float(raw_input())
print 'the prosess will be between', imp1, 'and', imp2, 'when do you want to stop the opperation'
stop_at = float(raw_input())


while True:
    num = random.randint(imp1, imp2)
    if num == stop_at:
        print
        print
        print stop_at, "were found after", ..., 'tryes'
        print '                   '
        break
    print num
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a counter

```
imp1 = int(raw_input("Enter low guess"))
imp2 = int(raw_input("Enter high guess"))
stop_at = int(raw_input("Enter the number you want guessed"))

i = 0
while True:
    i += 1
    num = random.randint(imp1, imp2)
    if num == stop_at:
        print "\n\n{0} was found after {1} tries\n\n".format(stop_at, i)
    print num
```

Answer (score 0):

First, You can't use `float` values as input parameters for `random.randint` function. Input parameters must be of type `integer`.

Second, same goes for `stop_at`. It must be `integer`, since `random.randint` will return `integer` (it MIGHT be `float`, but only if it is in form `2.0`, `11.0`...).

Third, You should introduce counter and increase it in `if` part of the code to get number of hits. Also, You should introduce counter which will be placed right inside `while` loop which will tell You how many loops were there.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce some count variable that you will increment with each loop pass.

```
cnt = 0
while True:
    num = random.randint(imp1, imp2)
    cnt += 1
    if num == stop_at:
        print
        print
        print stop_at, "were found after tryes {}".format(cnt)
        print
        break
    print num
```

Comment: op asks how many times the action is repeated before hitting stop_at. The loop breaks when finds at_stop so matching how many times stop_at was matched will always return 1